Handle argument when back screen in flutter
I'm have problem when upgrade from flutter version 3.7 to version 3.24
Situation: I have one screen. I pushNamed to second screen. In case User interact  with data and save data. When back to prev screen, I will reload data:
To resolve this problem: I used:
at second screen:
 WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: (){
        context.pop(hasChanged);
        return Future.value(true);
      },
    )

At the first screen: I Used
var hasChanged = await context.pushNamed(ApplicationRouteName.secondScreen);
if(hasChanged is bool){
  _handleReload();
}

However: In version 3.24, WillPopScope was decrepted. Instead, It's use PopScope with onPopInvokedWithResult.
I writed:
 PopScope(
      onPopInvokedWithResult: (_,__){
        if(hasChanged){
          Navigator.pop(context, true);
        }else{
          Navigator.pop(context, false);
        }
      },

And I had the following problem:
ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5350 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
#0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:50:61)
#1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
#2      NavigatorState.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:5350:12)
#3      Navigator.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:2665:27)
#4      _ChannelScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:iptv/features/channel/presentations/screens/channel_screen.dart:59:21)
#5      PopScope._callPopInvoked (package:flutter/src/widgets/pop_scope.dart:137:30)
#6      _PopScopeState.onPopInvokedWithResult (package:flutter/src/widgets/pop_scope.dart:172:12)
#7      ModalRoute.onPopInvokedWithResult (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:1780:16)
#8      NavigatorState.pop (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:5362:19)
#9      NavigatorState.maybePop (p<…>

I have looked into many documents and know that this is affected to fit android 14. However there is no reference that can replace in my situation.
I really hope to receive support from the community.
